# Foundation off-canvas-menu + Fullpage js conflict

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation + fullpage js .

The hamburger menu is there, but when i click it, nothing happens.

```
<div class="hide-for-large-only ">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <nav class="tab-bar">
              <section class="left-small">
                <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
              </section>

              <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                <h1 class="title">company name</h1>
              </section>

            </nav>

            <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
              <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label>Menus</label></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </aside>

            <section class="main-section">
              <!-- content goes here -->
            </section>

            <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have another navigation bar that will display only on large screens, and hide on medium and down.

```
<header>
        <nav id="menu" class="hide-for-medium-down">
            <a data-menuanchor="home" href="#home"><img class="logo" alt="" src="img/logo1.png"></a>
                <ul class="menutext">
                    <li data-menuanchor="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="products"><a href="#prodcuts">products</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="contactus"><a href="#contactus">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. I'm not knowledgeable enough to know why it happens. But I found my fix to be to initialize foundation at the bottom of the pages. Something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).foundation();
});
</script>
```

Not sure if this is right, but it worked for me. Don't think there is enough information to completely answer the question without just taking a stab at it.